# How to use CCCryptorStatus for DES encryption if NSString in iPhone? objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, des

Can anyone help how to use CCCryptorStatus for DES encryption of NSString. I want to pass des encrypted password to the API for login.

Comment: You need to add much more information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The simpliest and secure method is to use https. With https the data and qyerry parameters are all encrypted for transmission over the Internet.
2. Do not use DES, it is to weak for curent work. Instead use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) if you need to do your own encryption.
3. If you do your own encryption how will you get the encryption on both the client and server and keep it secure?